# Releasing all the autoreleased objects in iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

I am creating an iPhone application, in that I used ARC for memory management. In this application user has the option for login and logout. So, any user can login to their account at any time from the same device.

So, I think, as I am using ARC, the releasing of the objects is happening at some points in the future. So, when multiple users login does that cause any issue? Like should I manually send release message to all the objects in the autorelease pool when a user logout?

Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ARC automatically manages "autorelease" objects so that you don't need to worry about it. Under ARC I don't think it is even possible to send a release message to the pool. It will automatically release those objects when it decides they are no longer needed.

Comment: I agree to that, but I afraid, for some objects, for different users we need to assign different values. So, does it make any conflict? I am not sure, but I just want to confirm it.

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. If a new user logs in, based on the way your code is, It will create new objects or set them to different values if you reuse the objects with the new user data.

Answer (score 1):

Never manually release objects with ARC. With ARC all the releases are automatically handled.
If your concern is over the fact whether data of the first user gets lost then answer is no.
When new user logs in new instances of variables are created. thats all.